# magento 2 add slick slider to recently viewed products

Tags: magento2.3

I am trying to add slick slider to recently viewed products on product page in

> app/design/frontend/_YOUR_VENDOR_/YOUR_THEME/Magento_Catalog/web/template/product/list/listing.html

How can i add it ?

Comment: You can follow this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/297809/magento-2-add-owl-carousel-to-recently-viewed-products

Comment: please have a look https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/293808/how-to-add-slick-slider-to-magento-2-product-grid/293842#293842